# Date formatting returning FALSE

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm getting dates back like this from a mySQL query: `2017-06-23 20:08:58`

I'm trying to do this to get the dates back in a simpler format:

```
$response = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$items = array();
foreach ($response as &$value) {
    $items[] = date_format($value['date_added'], 'Y-m-d');
}
```

However, this returns only `false` for every date.

If I try

```
$response = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $items = array();
    foreach ($response as &$value) {
        $items[] = $value['date_added'];
    }
```

I get back the dates in this format (2017-06-23 20:08:58), so I know the query works, but how do I format these dates "on the fly?"

Comment: You could just cast it as a date in the query rather than a datetime. Do you need the full format later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date_format` wants a DateTimeInterface object instead of a string. What you can do is use mysql's date_format in your query so you don't need to do it with PHP.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date_added
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Great answer.  If you ever want to do it in PHP use `date()` instead of `date_format()`.